# javascript - сравнить 2 даты - почему все логические операторы false?

Tags: javascript, дата

Сравниваю 2 даты, всегда получаю false - почему???

```
currentDt = new Date();
currentDt.setHours(0,0,0,0);

reportDt = new Date(record.data.reportDt);

console.log('currentDt = ' + currentDt);
console.log('reportDt = ' + reportDt);
console.log(currentDt > reportDt);
console.log(currentDt < reportDt);
console.log(currentDt == reportDt);
console.log(currentDt === reportDt);
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ

```
currentDt = Sat Jun 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russian Standart Time)
reportDt = Sat Jun 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russian Standart Time)
false
false
false
false
```

ПОЧЕМУ???
Как их сравнить?
Функция Ext.Date.format(reportDt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') тоже не отрабатывала, сравнивала только по числам, игнорируя месяц.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `new Date();` создает объект. А объекты нельзя сравнивать вот так. Даже если они пустые, они всё равно разные и дадут false:

```js
console.log( {} == {} );
console.log( {x: 1} == {x: 1} );
```

А в вашем случае, можно использовать `.getTime()` который возвращает количество миллисекунд, прошедших от 01.01.1970 до установленной даты.

```js
let currentDt = new Date();

currentDt.setHours(0,0,0,0);

let reportDt = new Date('Sat Jun 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300');

console.log( typeof currentDt + ' / ' + typeof reportDt );

let x = currentDt.getTime();
let y = reportDt.getTime();

console.log('currentDt: ' + x + '\n reportDt: ' + y);
console.log(x > y);
console.log(x < y);
console.log(x == y);
console.log(x === y);
```

Comment: TL;DR: в случае объектов сравниваются ссылки, а не значения.